# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '20,21' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT     SUM(PayAmount)
FROM          TeacherPayment_Detail
WHERE      TeacherPaymentId IN (TeacherPayment.Advance_IDs)
```

i want the sum up of advance taken by a teacher by this query. where `Advance_IDs` are Id's of recods of advance taken by teacher. but sql giving following error.

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '20,21' to data type int.
```

note that if `Advance_IDs` has one value then error not occure this error occure on more then one value
I explored for conversion the nvarchar to int by splitting function but i don't found the functions of my requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is due to

```
SELECT     SUM(PayAmount)
FROM          TeacherPayment_Detail
WHERE      TeacherPaymentId IN ('20,21' )
```

but SQL Server Expects

```
 SELECT     SUM(PayAmount)
    FROM          TeacherPayment_Detail
    WHERE      TeacherPaymentId IN ('20','21' )
```

So you can do any one of the following

1. write some function which will tokenise the '20,21' to '20','21' in
   SQL (it is best to do a function which will returns a table)

   SELECT     SUM(PayAmount)
       FROM          TeacherPayment_Detail
       WHERE      TeacherPaymentId IN (select val from Function_Split(TeacherPayment.Advance_IDs )
2. Pass value in the form 'val1','val2'

**When it is only one value it will be 'val' and works, but when it is more than one value, it will 'val1,val2'. so this wont works causing error. It will work if you pass like this 'val1','val2'**

** Function **

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetTokenizeValue
(
    @strCSVString VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS 
@Result TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    ID int
)
AS
BEGIN


; WITH CTE(Start, [Stop]) AS
(
  SELECT  1, CHARINDEX(',' , @strCSVString )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  [Stop] + 1, CHARINDEX(',' ,@strCSVString  , [Stop] + 1)
  FROM CTE
  WHERE [Stop] > 0
)
INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@strCSVString , Start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN [Stop]-Start ELSE 4000 END) AS stringValue
FROM CTE

RETURN 
END
```

**your select query will be**

```
SELECT     SUM(PayAmount)
FROM          TeacherPayment_Detail
WHERE      TeacherPaymentId IN (select * from dbo.GetTokenizeValue(TeacherPayment.Advance_IDs))
```

Comment: thank you for help me. I understand the problem. but I don't know how to create a function into sql. can you send me the function.

Comment: i modified the answer by adding function. please try this

Comment: thank you for helping me.  I got my result successfully. I already used Ritesh D link before your post but your function is also helpful for men.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a split function using the following link:
[Convert Comma Separated String to Table Column](http://riteshdmakwana.blogspot.in/2012/04/sql-server-convert-comma-separated.html)

Comment: Can you provide additional information and use the link as a reference? In it's current state this is a [link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Use following user defined function

```
Create Function dbo.CsvToInt ( @Array varchar(1000)) 
returns @IntTable table (IntValue int) AS 
begin 
declare @separator char(1) 
set @separator = ',' 
declare @separator_position 
int declare @array_value varchar(1000) 
set @array = @array + ',' 
while patindex('%,%' , @array) <> 0 
begin 
select @separator_position = patindex('%,%' , @array) 
select @array_value = left(@array, @separator_position - 1) 
Insert @IntTable Values (Cast(@array_value as int)) 
select @array = stuff(@array, 1, @separator_position, '') 
end 
return end
```

Use as below

```
Select * from dbo.CsvToInt('1,5,11')
```

In your case

```
SELECT     SUM(PayAmount)
FROM          TeacherPayment_Detail
WHERE      TeacherPaymentId IN (Select * from dbo.CsvToInt(TeacherPayment.Advance_IDs))
```