# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '6,7' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 with a column of type `NVARCHAR` that stores list of transactions, comma separated, eg `6,4,1`

Question is: I want to do an `IN` clause that refers to the content of that column, say

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTransactions t 
INNER JOIN pCollections pc ON pc.transc = t.transc 
WHERE t.idnt IN (pc.fields)
```

The column `pc.fields` stores content like '6,7'. Instead I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '6,7' to data type int.

Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: "I have a Table in SQL Server with a field of type NVARCHAR that stores list of Transactions, comma separated, eg 6,4,1" - fix your design.

Comment: It's not my design, am inheriting this from a system that already runs with thousands of transactions already.

Comment: " thousands of transactions " is hardly large. If you do not want horrendous performance problems when you have millions of transactions , I suggest you fix the awful design.

Comment: While I appreciate your feedback, I wished it would have been the case, I don't have access to the code. I'm just doing a reporting system for the application, directly from the Database, not through the system

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? SQL Server 2016 supports [string_split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt684588.aspx) function, which makes things easier.

Comment: @qxg SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '20,21' to data type int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10394531/3002584).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a parser.  The TVF below is much faster than the recursive cte approach.  Can be used in the WHERE or even within a CROSS APPLY

**For Example (notice the return sequence RetSeq if that needs to be leveraged)**

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('6,7,4',',')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       6
2       7
3       4
```

**The UDF if needed**

```
CREAT FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = Substring(@String, A.N, A.L) 
    From   cte4 A
);
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

**A second option if you ever need to parse varchar(max).  Only a smidge slower than the -8K version**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try and get back to you shortly

Comment: @DennysHenry Just let me know if I can help

Comment: @DennysHenry Good to know.  I use it all the time :)

Comment: @DennysHenry Added a second function just for fun

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a CSV string parsing function. And use it to parse the string `'6,7'` and return as a result. There are lots of those available, just search for it

after that, change your query the WHERE clause to something like

```
WHERE t.idnt IN (SELECT value FROM dbo.csv_parse_function(pc.fields))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use `like` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM myTransactions t 
INNER JOIN pCollections pc ON pc.transc = t.transc 
WHERE ','+ pc.fields +',' like '%,'+cast(t.idnt as nvarchar(max)) + ',%'
```

I think this will helps you